# Dockerfile CMD Command not using variable

Tags: docker, dockerfile

In a dockerfile copy worked with the variable work_dir

```
ARG WORK_DIR=/home/myuser/work
COPY ./code $WORK_DIR/code
```

but the command does seem not to use it

```
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "${WORK_DIR}/start.sh" ]
```

is answered with

```
sh: 1: /start.sh: not found
```

omitting the workdir. How to properly add a path variable to the command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dockerfile `ARG` are only usable as environment variables in `RUN` commands; they are not visible to the `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` when the container runs.

The most direct workaround to this is to republish the `ARG` as an `ENV`, which *is* visible when the container eventually runs

```bash
ENV WORK_DIR=${WORK_DIR}
CMD ${WORK_DIR}/start.sh
```

However, there's rarely if ever a need to configure the container-internal filesystem paths.  For the current working directory in particular, you can use the Dockerfile `WORKDIR` directive to set the current directory, and then use relative paths to that directory.

```bash
                           # no ARG WORK_DIR setting
WORKDIR /home/myuser/work  # also consider something shorter like /app
COPY ./code ./code         # host path -> container path relative to WORKDIR
CMD ["./start.sh"]         # relative to WORKDIR
```

Comment: thanks for the explenation also. That did work like charm. actullay I would like my installation to run inside docker and also natively